# How to loop through a range while already looping through another range

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

Good day

I'm trying to loop through a range and while in that range I need to loop through another.

Although this does work, it'll give you an idea of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
    ' Select cell M5, *first line of data*.
    Range("M5").Select
    ' Set Do loop to stop when an empty cell is reached.
    Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
        strReg = ActiveCell.Value
        dteDate = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
        lngRate = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value
        Range("G5").Select
        Do Until blnFound Or IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
            If ActiveCell.Value = strReg Then
                If ActiveCell.Offset(0, -3) <= dteDate And ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2) >= dteDate Then
                     blnFound = True
                     '... add more logic here
                End If
            End If
            ' Step down 1 row from present location.
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        Loop
        ' Step down 1 row from present location.
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop
```

Thanks for taking the time.

Rob

Comment: More info would help, as to what you layout you have, and what you want to achieve

Comment: All the data is on one sheet. I have a list of vehicles, dates and costs with a corresponding list of invoices, vehicles and the dates those vehicles were hired out.
i.e.:
[vehicle, date, cost]

[Invoice, Vehicle, Start Date, End Date]

I need to loop through the first set of data and take each vehicle and find it in the second set. If it's in the second set I need to determine is the date falls within the start and end date.

Comment: It seems like the bounds of your loops are defined really well, so if your "inner" loop doesn't have duplicate vehicles you could do a `Range.Find` for the value you identify in the "outer" loop. If duplicates ARE an issue, could you post a screenshot or sample of the worksheet?

Comment: Thanks Dan for your answer, it's a great help. What I ended up doing though was using a SUMIFS formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick implementation of this loop starting off with a file that looks like this:

[image: start]

```
Option Explicit
Sub LoopThroughVehicles()

Dim MySheet As Worksheet
Dim CostRange As Range, InvoiceRange As Range, _
    FoundRange As Range, Vehicle As Range
Dim LastRow As Long, CostVehicleCol As Long, _
    InvoiceVehicleCol As Long
Dim CostDate As Date, StartDate As Date, _
    EndDate As Date

'assign variables and ranges for easy reference
CostVehicleCol = 13 'column M
InvoiceVehicleCol = 7 'column G
Set MySheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
With MySheet
    LastRow = .Range("M" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End With
Set CostRange = Range(MySheet.Cells(LastRow, CostVehicleCol), MySheet.Cells(5, CostVehicleCol))
With MySheet
    LastRow = .Range("G" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End With
Set InvoiceRange = Range(MySheet.Cells(LastRow, InvoiceVehicleCol), MySheet.Cells(5, InvoiceVehicleCol))

'search for each vehicle
For Each Vehicle In CostRange
    Set FoundRange = InvoiceRange.Find(What:=Vehicle.Value, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
    'if the vehicle is found, assign dates and compare
    If Not FoundRange Is Nothing Then
        CostDate = Vehicle.Offset(0, 1).Value
        StartDate = FoundRange.Offset(0, -3).Value
        EndDate = FoundRange.Offset(0, -2).Value
        If CostDate >= StartDate And CostDate <= EndDate Then
            'do stuff if cost date is in date range
            MsgBox ("Cool, " & Vehicle.Value & " is in the date range!")
        Else
            'do other stuff if cost date is not in date range
            MsgBox ("Uh oh, " & Vehicle.Value & " is NOT in the date range!")
        End If
    End If
Next Vehicle

End Sub
```